# CSS -the text is "staying" in one line

Tags: css, newline

I have  CSS problem. **Here is JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63NHM/1/**

The problem is that the main text, under the title is not automatic down to a new line, he "staying" in one line which is not good.

Here is the CSS of this section

```
#trackdescription {
    text-align: justify;
    max-width: 500px;
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 320px;
    display:block;
}
```

How can I fix this? Wish for help, thanks.

Comment: If you need filler text for the purpose of testing the layout, try a fake text generator like http://www.lipsum.com/.  Copy/pasting the same phrase repeatedly doesn't give you a good idea of how the real content will flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add [`word-break: break-all`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break) to `#trackdescription` - which works because the text is essentially one long word ..

http://jsfiddle.net/63NHM/2/

---

Although its a temporary fix using it in this context is actually bad practice, as this wasn't the intention of the `word-break` property. From the [Text Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break0):

> This option is used mostly in a context where the text is predominantly using CJK characters with few non-CJK excerpts and it is desired that the text be better distributed on each line.

Comment: Thank yoou so much! I have no idea befor that something like this exists, that exactly what I looked for. thanks againg!

Comment: Using `word-break: break-word` **breaks** words and should be avoided, except for special code notations in some cases and for languages that allow free breaking of words. In this case, it is impossible to be sure whether such breaking is OK, since the *real* content is hardly the string presented in the jsfiddle (and that string would not make sense).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela If you're formatting user submitted content, your choices are either break their mess, let their mess break your entire layout, or force breaks on the server side.  If its content you control, by all means *don't do that*.

Comment: @cimmanon, that’s speculative: is this about user-submitted content? Moreover, there are several other ways to deal with such content, and you can and should control it – but that’s a different topic.